# iPhone Media Player Framework accessing raw file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, audioqueueservices, mediaplayerservices

I'm interested in using the Media Player framework on iPhone to access audio in the user's library.  I want to be able to load a given audio file and then perform some specialised filtering on it.

Ideally I want to be able to directly load the audio file (or portion thereof for streaming) then use the audio converter services to perform decompression.  Once I have the linear PCM data I want to perform some filtering on it before supplying the audio directly to an audio queue.

Is this possible on iPhone?

If so, can anyone tell me how I would access the audio file directly?  Is it just a matter of using the "URL" to load it using NSFile (Presumably I obtain that through MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL)?  Or do I need to do something more complicated?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you get from `MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL` is an Assets Library URL. You can use it to initialize an `AVURLAsset`. Then create an `AVAssetReader` with the asset and add to it an `AVAssetReaderOutput` (instances of `AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput` or `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput`, depending on what you need). This latter object will finally give you access to the media data (`-copyNextSampleBuffer`).